# How to Generate random (a-z) len=4 and (0-9) len=2 in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem to generate any char with VB.Net, I have the code as PHP version. How do I create it in VB.Net?

**This my PHP code:**

```
function randomcodeAlpha($len="4") {
    $code = NULL;
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
        $char = chr(rand(48,122));
        while(!ereg("[A-Z]", $char)) {
            if($char == $lchar) { continue; }
            $char = chr(rand(48,90));
        }
        $pass .= $char;
        $lchar = $char;
    }
    return $pass;
} 

function randomcodeNumeric($len="2") {
    $code = NULL;
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++) {
        $char = chr(rand(48,122));
        while(!ereg("[0-9]", $char)) {
            if($char == $lchar) { continue; }
            $char = chr(rand(48,90));
        }
        $pass .= $char;
        $lchar = $char;
    }
    return $pass;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim str As string = RandomString(4, _chars)
    Dim num As string = RandomString(2, _nums)
End Sub

Private Const _chars As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Private Const _nums As String = "0123456789"
private shared readonly _randLock = new Object()
private shared readonly _rnd = New Random()

Private Shared Function RandomString(size As Integer, chars As String) As String
    Dim arr = New Char(size - 1) {}

    For i As Integer = 0 To size - 1
        SyncLock _randLock
           arr(i) = chars(_rnd.Next(chars.Length))
        End SyncLock 
    Next

    Return New String(arr)
End Function
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that when you call `RandomString` multiple times in a row with the same parameters, it will return the same string (because you use a new `Random` instance each time, and each instance uses the same seed). You could make `rnd` static to solve this:  `Static rnd = New Random()` instead of `Dim rnd = New Random()`

Comment: @sloth Yes that is true. But since `Random` is not thread safe having it an a static variable the `RandomString` function would also need to implement synchronization in that case.

Comment: thanks @Magnus , i have to try your source, but i have error like this ' Dump() is not a member of string'

Comment: @Magnus True, if you want thread safety you'll have to put some effort into it :-)

Comment: @WOrmInjectOr just remove the `.Dump()` that was just for writing to the console.

Comment: mr @Magnus yes its working fine, thanks somuch, i'll ask you next time sir, thanks you